# Combining two Gestures to form a new gesture

Tags: android

I have created two gestures on my emulator using the gestures builder class.I now want to combine these two gestures to create a new gesture.(Suppose i have two gestures,one which recognizes the letter A and another gesture which recognizes the letter B,I want to create a new gesture which will respond only when the user draws AB).

Comment: Not sure if its possible. You may need to get the gesture number of strokes, its paths and its lengths. Individually the gestures could be stored in a library.
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html